# Unzip a file located on disk (maven-assembly-plugin)

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to output all the files required to run a project in a `./target/dist` folder. I'd like to bundle a JRE while preparing the assembly. The JRE is located at the base directory of my project and is contained in a zip file called `jre.zip`.

**How can `./jre.zip` be unpacked in the `./target/dist` folder?**

Here's the XML for my assembly.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>dist</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <baseDirectory>./</baseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>./</directory>
            <outputDirectory>./jre</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</source>
            <destName>${artifactId}.jar</destName>
            <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
        </file>     
    </files>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can unpack dependencies with the Maven Assembly Plugin, i'm pretty surr that won't work with the jre....

I suggest you unpack the jre before executing the Assembly plugin like so

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>prepare</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
                <echo message="prepare phase" />
                <unzip src="jre.zip" dest="target/jre"/>
            </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: see https://github.com/haggard1979/simpleThings/tree/master/unzipWithMaven for an example